# myhdl constraints associating multiple pins to a variable

Tags: byte, constraints, bit, words, myhdl

I will be using an iCE40HX8K

given the evaluation boards constraint file

```
set_io LED3 A2  
set_io LED7 B3  
...  
etc
```

whats the best way to bundle all 8 LED's into one variable
I had trouble associating things with my constraint file and ended up with something like this

```
#main module
def ledcount(LED1, LED2, LED3, LED4, LED5, LED6, LED7, LED8, clk):
```

when writing a register to the LED's I'm having to resort to this

```
op.next = op + 1
LED1 = op[0]
...
LED8 = op[7]
```

I'm generating verilog like this... (I did have single sliced bits from a single signal here but it seemed to cause problems - ie LED3 in constrains not assigning to anything)

```
clock = Signal(bool(0))
l1 = Signal(bool(0))
...
l8 = Signal(bool(0))
toVerilog(ledcount, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, clock)
```

bad enough but its going to become unwieldy with a parallel address and data bus ...

I notice in the generated verilog LED1-8 are specified like this

```
input LED1;
...
input LED8;
```

before the always clause
and inside the always

```
reg LED1;
...
reg LED8;
```

While all this compiles (Hardware should arrive tomorrow!) and it might(?) even work... I'm sure it can be done better!

I'd be quite happy handling the LED's together as a single byte using bit manipulation...

Comment: op.next = op + 1  
LED1.next = op[0]  
...  
LED8.next = op[7]  plus a few other errors, but still would like to know how to bundle LED1-LED8 ports together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward is to change your constraints to

```
set_io LED[2] A2
```

and then use a single LED port

```
def ledcount(leds, clk)
```

and it can be converted to

```
clk = Signal(bool(0))
leds = Signal(intbv(0)[8:])
myhdl.toVerilog(ledcount, leds, clk)
```

Comment: nice... thats so much easier! MyHDL is sooo much easier that struggling with obese "official" tools !